# Change storm zookeeper server in storm.yaml

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I want to point my storm cluster to 3 zookeeper nodes. From my understanding, I should just change storm.yaml configuration in nimbus and supervisor nodes without stopping any of the nodes. Is it correct?

How should I validate my change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to restart Nimbus and the supervisors once you've updated storm.yaml in order for them to pick up the change.

I'm assuming you currently have 1 Zookeeper node? In that case, you can validate your change after updating to 3 by stopping the Zookeeper node and checking that your Nimbus and supervisors keep running.

An alternative is to enable debug logging for `org.apache.curator`, it will most likely log which nodes it is connecting to.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes, currently I have one zookeeper node. I am running around 130 topologies in my cluster. Do I need to change storm.yaml file in every node (nimbus and supervisor)? Do I need to re deploy all my topologies after I am done with the changes?

Comment: Yes, you need to change it on every node. You don't need to redeploy the topologies.